# How to use tidy evaluation with column name as strings?

Tags: r, dplyr, eval, tidy

I've read most of the documentation about tidy evaluation and programming with dplyr but cannot get my head around this (simple) problem.

I want to programm with dplyr and give column names as strings as input to the function.

```
df <- tibble(
  g1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  g2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1),
  a = sample(5),
  b = sample(5)
)

my_summarise <- function(df, group_var) {
  df %>%
    group_by(group_var) %>%
    summarise(a = mean(a))
}

my_summarise(df, 'g1')
```

This gives me `Error : Column 'group_var' is unknown`.

What must I change inside the my_summarise function in order to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use also `ensym` with `!!`

```
my_summarise <- function(df, group_var) {


  df %>%
    group_by(!!rlang::ensym(group_var)) %>%
    summarise(a = mean(a))
   }

my_summarise(df, 'g1')
```

---

Or another option is `group_by_at`

```
my_summarise <- function(df, group_var) {


      df %>%
        group_by_at(vars(group_var)) %>%
        summarise(a = mean(a))
       }

my_summarise(df, 'g1')
```

Comment: All the answers are good. I prefer to use `ensym` because it accepts arguments with and without quotes. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Convert the string column name to a bare column name using `as.name()` and then use the new {{}} (read Curly-Curly) operator as below:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  g1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  g2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1),
  a = sample(5),
  b = sample(5)
)

my_summarise <- function(df, group_var) {

  grp_var <- as.name(group_var)

  df %>%
    group_by({{grp_var}}) %>%
    summarise(a = mean(a))
}

my_summarise(df, 'g1')
```

Comment: Will this function then still work if I input the variable directly and not as a string? Or is a type catching needed in this function?

Comment: if you are going to give the column name directly without quotes, then you don't need the line `grp_var <- as.name(group_var)`. You new function would be as follows:
```
my_summarise <- function(df, group_var) {

  df %>%
    group_by({{group_var}}) %>%
    summarise(a = mean(a))
}

```

Comment: yes but suppose I want to "proof" this function against both types of arguments (string and literal), would the ```as.name``` still work or would I need to implement a type check at the beginning of the function? This is purely out of curiosity as I am not OP.

Comment: you can use `ensym` to cover both cases. you will need to use the  `!!` (bang-bang) operator in combination with `ensym` from rlang package.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sym` and `!!`

```
my_summarise <- function(df, group_var) {


  df %>%
    group_by(!!sym(group_var)) %>%
    summarise(a = mean(a))
   }

my_summarise(df, 'g1')

# A tibble: 2 x 2
     g1     a
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  3.5 
2     2  2.67
```